# Bookmark a page to be accessed on both mobile and desktop Chrome easily

Tags: chrome-for-android

It looks like that one bookmark instance can only exist on one of Chrome folders. Such that when I want to visit a site from both my phone and my laptop, I always have to change my bookmark folder back and forth depend on where I stored that bookmark page.

Can I bookmark a page and view it on both mobile folder and desktop folder?

Answer (score 1):

Use slightly different URLs as bookmarks (e.g. add `&dummy=1` at the end of one of them) so that they are "different bookmarks".

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, you can, but you have to synchronize Google Chrome with Google Account.** You can change synchronization interval, etc., etc., in device settings (Accounts). How to force make bookmarks synchronization, you can read [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2DC6fgmtqxY%5B1-25-false%5D).

Comment: I have syned my account on both Desktop and Mobile, but I think it is exactly the synchronization that caused the issue because one instance of bookmark can only exist in either mobile folder or desktop folder. If I bookmark this page on Chrome Desktop, then bookmark this page again on mobile bookmark. This page disappears from the Desktop bookmark.